# Rendering a custom select list in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm a really confused by the different options of drawing in QT. To make it clear, I'm not asking for code. Just I'd be so thankful if someone can shed a light on the best way to implement that. I don't think it's very complicated!

Here is the result that i'm looking for!

[image]

The main idea is to have a textinput at the top and a list of suggestion above with matched results.

At the moment, I use a `QTreeWidget`, and add rows with a `QTreeWidgetItem` with a `QStringList`. Obviously it doesn't look like the screenshot :) Should i use a `QItemDelegate` to handle the drawing? I did some research, but it looks a bit painfull to draw with a QPainter. I thought it would be easier to implement a custom widget and replicate it somehow with maybe a `QListView`? `QListWidget`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could indeed try to use a `QListView` to draw your combo, it might be a tad simpler to handle than a `QTreeWidget`.

Unfortunately, I'm afraid you will have to subclass a `QItemDelegate` (or some other kind of delegate) to handle a custom display of your data (eg, mixing an icon, a few strings and a date field...).

For the data itself, you may want to consider using a `QStandardItemModel`. Because you only want to display some data, overwriting the `data` method should be enough (along the `rowCount` and `columCount` methods, of course).

Comment: thanks for your help! i've been able to play with setItemWidget and add some QLabel wrapped in a QWidget. I know it's not as efficient as a QPainter. Actually, I don't know how to "bind" the data on each row. I did some research on the QListView or QTreeView as you advised, the model approch is very clean but it's a lot of work just for a suggestion list imo... :/

Comment: I just edited my answer with more pointers. Let me know what else you need.

Comment: ah gosh! I didnt think to override it. I stared at this method, saw there is a QVariant somewhere.... and I didnt know how to put a pointer in that strange thing. Thanks, I'll consider it :p

Comment: A note to anyone who reads this answer: From assistant: _Note that QStyledItemDelegate has taken over the job of drawing Qt's item views. We recommend the use of QStyledItemDelegate when creating new delegates._